# How to queryset filter for the latest entry for distinct entries in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model with the following entry:

```
Date modified       Account    Balance
12/03/15            BofA       $500
12/04/15            BofA       $550
12/02/15            Citibank   $300
12/03/15            Citibank   $230
```

How does use queryset to filter for the latest entry for each account?  In this case, I'm expecting 12/04/15 BofA $550 and 12/03/15 Citibank $230.

I have:

```
model.objects.filter(account.id=a.id).latest.distinct()
```

Comment: Can you try `from django.db.models import Max` then `model.objects.values('account', 'balance').annotate(latest=Max('date_modified'))`?

Comment: If you want all of this, order by latest date, you can use this in views        `Model.objects.all().order_by('date').reverse()`  Or you need only one latest value?

Comment: Maybe you can try to order by date and then use distinct on the account (if you're using postgresql) like  this : `model.objects.order_by('-date').distinct('account')`

Comment: @Alejo I have made bad experiences with this mixture of `order_by` and `distinct` with different fields specified for both: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: your db backend is MySQL, SQLite  or PostgreSQL ? the two first will need more logic in the view/model code. PostgreSQL can use  `.distict()` method with fields.

Comment: If you combine `order_by` and `distinct` in Postgres, make sure to include the fields from distinct in order_by: `model.objects.order_by('account', '-date').distinct('account')`

Comment: @schwobaseggl thanks for your correction, indeed it should include the field from distinct in order_by

Comment: @YonsySolis What if you have a SQLite as the backend? How would you deal with this?